# How to send an Order Confirmation email from script

Tags: php, magento, magento2

When I try sending an email from the root script in Magento I get the below error:

> ```
> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Missing required argument $debugHintsPath of Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Plugin\DebugHints.' in
> /var/www/html/2x/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:45
> Stack trace:
> 0 /var/www/html/2x/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Develop...', Array, Array)
> 1 /var/www/html/2x/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Develop...')
> 2 /var/www/html/2x/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(234):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Develop...')
> 3 /var/www/html/2x/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(149):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin('Magento\\Framewo...', 'debug_hints')
> 4 /var/www/html/2x/var/generati in /var/www/html/2x/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
> on line 45
> ```

Below is the code which I have used:

```
$orderid = '000000003';
$order = $obj->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
// print_r($order->getData());

$obj->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender')->send($order,true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using

```
$orderid = '000000003';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
$objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\OrderNotifier')->notify($order);
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting below error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Missing required argument $debugHintsPath of Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Plugin\DebugHints.' in /var/www/html/2x/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:45

Comment: kindly use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderNotifier 
if you are using this code in any module than you should clear cache and generation etc . 
BY :  rm -rf var/cache/ var/di/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/

Comment: Kindly update to latest stable version for Magento2. I am using same code with Release Magento 2.1.0-rc1 and it works perfectly 
REF : https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Comment: $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
this was working for me

Answer (score 5):

You can also change the recipient of the mail if you want :

```
$orderid = '000000338';
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
        $order->setCustomerEmail('custom@mail.com');
        $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\OrderNotifier')->notify($order);
```